# Android - OnClick open Image?

Tags: android-studio

I'm new in Android programming and I need a help!!!

I hava button on a middle on screen and I want to open an image when button is clicked. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKYy7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help]. This is not a free code-writing service nor tutorial site. You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working and what the expected result would be. As it stands, your question is "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to go to another activity assuming that your image viewer is on another activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Image.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

With main being the activity your on and image being the one with the image viewer.

Comment: Ok, I thought that, onClick I can make play a sound without a new activity, then I can open an image onClick without new activity. :)